# Add multiple key value pairs from a database table to a HashMap

Tags: java

I have three database tables defined below, column names mentioned in parenthesis:

```
Product (ProductID, Price, Last_Updated)

User (UserID, Name, Address, LocationID, Last_Updated)

Location (LocationID, Loc_Name, Last_Updated)
```

I want to use Java (JDK 1.5) to add all the column names of all the tables in one collection like a `HashMap`.

My problem is when a duplicate key is entered, the previous value is over ridden.

I am adding them like:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.add("ProductID", "Save the Product ID");
// ...
map.add("Last_Updated", "Save Last_Updated of Product table");
// ...
map.add("LocationID", "Save the LocationID");
// ...
map.add("Last_Updated", "Save Last_Updated of User table.");
```

Now the key `Last_Updated` is overridden with new value `Save Last_Updated of User table.`

But I want both the values.

Is there any way to implement this without using multiple `HashMap` structures?

Comment: Why don't you have one map per table?

Comment: Are you allowed to JDK 1.5 in code features, or in the extent of libraries?
Also, this looks like homework to me. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the table names as a prefix to your column names. Then you can separate "Product.Last_Updated", "User.Last_Updated" and "Location.Last_Updated".
Obviously you have to use a separator char that is not used in the names of your tables or columns; a '.' should do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add items with the same key, then this would be a possible solution

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

when adding an element:

```
public void add(String key, String value) {
    if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(value);
}
```

And when you want to access an element, then by the maps `get()` function you will get a List of strings, wich are the values for a key.

**However, it would be best to use a Multimap implementation:**

## Guava:

[`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) - You can see the concrete implementations in the javadoc.

```
Multimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
map.put("a", "Apple");
map.put("a", "Almonds");
Collection<String> valuesForA = map.get("a"); // List of ("Apple", "Almonds")
```

## Apache Commons

[`MultiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) - Examples and concrete implementations in the javadoc

Comment: There is a [multimap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) in the Apache Commons.

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited to JDK 5, but allowed to use libraries, check out a publicly available MultiMaps: Guava [has one](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html), as does [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not a denormalized table in an in-memory db like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or HSQL etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Seperator. Like Pipe symbol (|) or Dot (.)